# Why does an integral turn negative when its limits are switched?

Tags: integration

I’m trying to find the tension at the middle of a rotating rod in a gravity-free space. To do that, I had done some math and then I integrated with the limits $L/2$ to $L$.

This sounds like a math question but I’m not sure and I want to know: **Is there a significance to the negative sign in the result if I take the limits the other way around**?

Does this negative sign indicate direction or do I just suck at math?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking whether $\int_{L/2}^L f(x)\ dx = - \int_{L}^{L/2} f(x)\ dx$ (for $L>0$)? If so, the answer is yes by definition of an integral.

Comment: @pion integrating both ways makes sense but the second one you gave gives us a negative sign ,was adding that negative sign before that integral something fundamental ?

Comment: in my opinion this question was improperly migrated as presumably OP would like to know the physical interpretation of the negative sign in terms of the tension at the center of the rod

Comment: No, your intuition is correct.  The sign does indicate direction and, more generally and at a more advanced level, [orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)).

Comment: @hunter yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a basic characteristic of definite integrals that flipping the limits of integration will negate the result:

$$\int_a^b f(x)\ dx = -\int_b^a f(x)\ dx. $$

This can be seen by recalling the definition of an integral:

$$
\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{n}} f(x)\ dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(x_k)\ \Delta x.
$$

If we think of this as the sum of the areas of very narrow rectangles underneath the curve of $f(x)$, then $f(x_k)$ is the height of the rectangle at the point $x_k$ and $\Delta x$ is its width.

If there are $n$ rectangles between $x_{1}$ and $x_{n}$, then

$$\Delta x = \frac{x_{n} - x_{1}}{n},\label{delx}$$

the $k$th rectangle is found at

$$ x_k = x_1 + k\Delta x, \tag{1}\label{xk}$$

and the height of the $k$th rectangle is

$$ f(x_k) = f(x_{1} + k\Delta x) = f\left(x_{1} + \frac{x_{n} - x_{1}}{n} k\right)$$

which makes the integral

$$
\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{n}} f(x)\ dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(x_{1} + \frac{x_{n} - x_{1}}{n} k\right)\cdot \left(\frac{x_{n} - x_{1}}{n}\right).
$$

Because $x_{1}$, $x_{n}$, and $n$ are constants, we can move them outside the summation:

\begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{normal}
\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{n}} f(x)\ dx = \left(x_{n} - x_{1}\right) \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(x_{1} + \frac{x_{n} - x_{1}}{n} k\right).
\end{equation}

It’s important to note that the order in which we sum the values of $f(x)$ is unimportant due to the commutative property of addition. So instead of starting at $x=x_1$ and going to $x_n$, we could just as well start at the end and add backwards:

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{n}} f(x)\ dx &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(x_{n-k})\ \Delta x\\
&= \left(x_{n} - x_{1}\right)\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(x_{n - k}) \\
&= \left(x_{n} - x_{1}\right)\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(x_1 + \frac{x_n - x_1}{n}(n-k)\right) \\
&= \left(x_{n} - x_{1}\right)\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(x_n - \frac{x_n - x_1}{n} k\right)\tag{3}\label{reverse}
\end{align*}
$$

using \eqref{xk} to express $x_{n-k}$.

If your limits of integration are $\bf{x_{1} = a}$ and $\bf{x_{n} = b}$ then your integral when summing from start to end \eqref{normal} is

$$
\int_a^b f(x)\ dx = (b - a)\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(a + \frac{b - a}{n} k\right) \tag{4}\label{normalab}
$$

and when summing from end to start \eqref{reverse} is

$$
\int_a^b f(x)\ dx = \left(b - a\right)\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(b - \frac{b - a}{n} k \right).
$$

Now using the last equation let’s **reverse the limits** so that $\bf{x_{1} = b}$and $\bf{x_{n} = a}$ (i.e., swap all $a$s with $b$s and *vice versa*):

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_b^a f(x)\ dx &= \left(a - b\right)\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(a - \frac{a - b}{n} k \right) \\
& = \left(a - b\right)\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(a + \frac{b - a}{n} k \right) \\
&= - \left(b - a\right)\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(a + \frac{b - a}{n} k \right)
\end{align*}
$$

which is identical to the *negative value* of the unflipped integral \eqref{normalab}.